# Cannot boot raspberry Pi 3 connected to DVI with SDXC class 10 sd card

Tags: sd-card, power, hdmi, pi-3

How do I boot raspberry pi 3 with noobs installed on it.

Steps I have done so far.

1. Got NOOBS from the RPi downloads.
2. Samsung EVO 64gb micoSDXC class 10
3. Formatted the SD card with SDformatter from SD association

   - SD card File system exFAT
4. Copied NOOBS from ZIP to the SD card
5. Loaded SD card into raspberry pi
6. connected 5v - my phones charger cable.
7. connected to the monitor

All i can see is blank screen

Possible issues that may have happened.

I connected my HDMI to a DVI monitor. I tested with my laptop it connects. The HDMI to DVI works when connected to my laptop.

Could be fault on SD card format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some things you can try:

1. Make sure to format your SD card with fat32.
2. Look at your Raspberry Pi. What color is showing on the LED? If it's just showing RED then it's probably not able to find the correct files on your SD card. You will want to double check the SD card is all the way in.
3. Make sure you are putting all the files in the root of the SD card and not just inside of a folder that's in the root.
4. You can find more details here: http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up

I can add more here if that doesn't work and you give me some feedback. Good luck!

Comment: The light is red, I tried adjusting the SD card all the way up still shows red. Now i am trying to Format the SD card in FAT32 file system. WHen you said root what do you mean. Does it mean after formatting just copy and paste the NOOBS in SD card with exFAT file system.

Comment: You want to format it with fat32 and yes root means copy the files onto the the card but not inside a folder.

Comment: Just had to convert my SD card filesystem from exFAT to FAT32

Answer (score 0):

Ok heres the deal. Everything went well including use of HDMI to DVI converter.

The main thing i had to do was to FORMAT the SD card in FAT32 file system as raspberry is not equipped to handle exFat system.